# regex to exclude the tag details which having a particular attribute and select only specific tags

Tags: javascript, regex

from the bellow tags i want to select only some specific tag (tagA|tagB) details which doesn't have any "id" attribute by using regex.

```
<span class="online"><tagA xmlns="http://www.xyz.com/xml/ja/dtd">A1</tagA><tagB id="tg1" xmlns="http://www.xyz.com/xml/ja/dtd">B1</tagB></span>
<span class="online"><tagA id="tg2" xmlns="http://www.xyz.com/xml/ja/dtd">A2</tagA><tagB xmlns="http://www.xyz.com/xml/ja/dtd">B2</tagB></span>
<tagA id="tg3" xmlns="http://www.xyz.com/xml/ja/dtd">A3</tagA>
<tagB id="tg4" xmlns="http://www.xyz.com/xml/ja/dtd">B3</tagB>
<tagC id="tg5" xmlns="http://www.xyz.com/xml/ja/dtd">C1/tagC>
<tagA xmlns="http://www.xyz.com/xml/ja/dtd">A4</tagA>
<tagB xmlns="http://www.xyz.com/xml/ja/dtd">B4</tagB>
<tagC xmlns="http://www.xyz.com/xml/ja/dtd">C2</tagC>
<tagA>A5</tagA>
<tagB>B5</tagB>
<tagC>C3</tagC>
<span class="online"><i><tagA xmlns="http://www.xyz.com/xml/ja/dtd">A6</tagA></i><b><tagB id="tg6" xmlns="http://www.xyz.com/xml/ja/dtd">B6</tagB></b></span>
<span class="online"><i><tagA id="tg7" xmlns="http://www.xyz.com/xml/ja/dtd">A7</tagA></i><b><tagB xmlns="http://www.xyz.com/xml/ja/dtd">B7</tagB></b></span>
```

as a result i should get only the details of :

```
<tagA xmlns="http://www.xyz.com/xml/ja/dtd">A1</tagA>
<tagB xmlns="http://www.xyz.com/xml/ja/dtd">B2</tagB>

<tagA xmlns="http://www.xyz.com/xml/ja/dtd">A4</tagA>
<tagB xmlns="http://www.xyz.com/xml/ja/dtd">B4</tagB>
<tagA>A5</tagA>
<tagB>B5</tagB>

<tagA xmlns="http://www.xyz.com/xml/ja/dtd">A6</tagA>
<tagB xmlns="http://www.xyz.com/xml/ja/dtd">B7</tagB>
```

Comment: Are non-regexp solutions acceptable?

Comment: XML parsing with regexps is often not a good idea as XML is not a regular language and therefore can't be parsed with regular expressions. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) for the results of using regexps for XML parsing. Having said that, for very limited and well-defined cases like this one, it would probably work as in the answer below.

Answer (score 2):

This regex would match even if it is nested

```
<(?!.*?\sid=)(.*?)(\s+.*?)?>.*?</\1>
```

`.*?` matches 0 to many characters lazily

`(?!.*?id=)` is a negative lookahead that checks whether there is an id attribute and if it is will not match further

anything matched within `()` is captured in a `group`

`\1` refers to the `first` matched group..

You can try it [here](http://regexpal.com/)

Comment: Watch out for nested tags: this pattern applied to `<tagA>Dell<tagC>Inc.</tagC></tagA>` will match only `<tagA>Dell<tagC>Inc.</tagC>`.

Comment: Yep, this will allow different nested tags. But it will still break on `<tagA>Dell<tagA>Inc.</tagA></tagA>`.

Comment: How about `<tag cid="123">text</tag>` ?

Comment: @Ωmega ur solution is the best..i want to delet the ans but dont want to loose +30 rep ;)

Comment: thanks for u'r reply. but i've done a little change in requirement. i've updated the original question...

Answer (score 1):

Use regex pattern

```
<(\S+)(?![^<>]*\bid=).*?<\/\1>
```

Comment: thanks for u'r reply. but i've done a little change in requirement. i've updated the original question...

Comment: @pks - Then go with `<(tag[AB])(?![^<>]*\bid=).*?<\/\1>`

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would do it:

```
/<(tag[A-Z]+)(?:\s+(?!id=)\w+="[^"]+")*>\w+<\/\1>/i
```

Breaking it down:

- `<(tag[A-Z]+)` matches the opening tag and captures its name in group #1
- `(?:\s+(?!id=)\w+="[^"]+")*` consumes the attributes one at a time, after checking that the attribute's name is not `id`
- `>\w+</\1>` finishes off the opening tag, then consumes the content and the closing tag

You may need to tweak parts of it, especially the `\w+` sequences.  Lacking familiarity with your data, I tossed those in to serve as placeholders.